# Django querysets optimization - preventing selection of annotated fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-annotate

Let's say I have following models:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    ...

class Note(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, related_name='notes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
```

and I want to select *Invoices that have some notes*. I would write it using `annotate`/`Exists` like this:

```
Invoice.objects.annotate(
    has_notes=Exists(Note.objects.filter(invoice_id=OuterRef('pk')))
).filter(has_notes=True)
```

This works well enough, filters only Invoices with notes. However, this method results in the **field being present in the query result**, which **I don't need** and means worse performance (SQL has to execute the subquery 2 times).

I realize I could write this using [`extra(where=)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra) like this:

```
Invoice.objects.extra(where=['EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM note WHERE invoice_id=invoice.id)'])
```

which would result in the ideal SQL, but in general it is discouraged to use `extra` / raw SQL.
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove annotations from the SELECT clause using `.values()` query set method. The trouble with `.values()` is that you have to enumerate all names you want to keep instead of names you want to skip, and `.values()` returns dictionaries instead of model instances.

Django internaly keeps the track of removed annotations in 
`QuerySet.query.annotation_select_mask`. So you can use it to tell Django, which annotations to skip even wihout `.values()`:

```
class YourQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def mask_annotations(self, *names):
        if self.query.annotation_select_mask is None:
            self.query.set_annotation_mask(set(self.query.annotations.keys()) - set(names))
        else:
            self.query.set_annotation_mask(self.query.annotation_select_mask - set(names))
        return self
```

Then you can write:

```
invoices = (Invoice.objects
  .annotate(has_notes=Exists(Note.objects.filter(invoice_id=OuterRef('pk'))))
  .filter(has_notes=True)
  .mask_annotations('has_notes')
)
```

to skip `has_notes` from the SELECT clause and still geting filtered invoice instances. The resulting SQL query will be something like:

```
SELECT invoice.id, invoice.foo FROM invoice
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT note.id, note.bar FROM notes WHERE note.invoice_id = invoice.id) = True
```

Just note that `annotation_select_mask` is internal Django API that can change in future versions without a warning.

Comment: I knew about `values`, but I needed the queryset to return model instances. But the other trick with `annotation_select_mask` is pretty cool and works perfectly! Nice find!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've just noticed in [Django 3.0 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#filtering-on-a-subquery-or-exists-expressions), that they've updated how `Exists` works and can be used directly in `filter`:

```
Invoice.objects.filter(Exists(Note.objects.filter(invoice_id=OuterRef('pk'))))
```

This will ensure that the subquery will not be added to the **SELECT** columns, which may result in a better performance.

> **Changed in Django 3.0:**
>
> In previous versions of Django, it was necessary to first annotate and then filter against the annotation. This resulted in the annotated value always being present in the query result, and often resulted in a query that took more time to execute.

Still, if someone knows a better way for Django 1.11, I would appreciate it. We really need to upgrade :(

Answer (score 2):

We can filter for `Invoice`s that have, when we perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, no `NULL` as `Note`, and make the query distinct (to avoid returning the same `Invoice` twice).

```
Invoice.objects.filter(notes__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Comment: ahh right, I actually use this pattern somewhere else, but I couldn't use in my real case - I oversimplified the example and in reality I use `select_for_update` and some additional filters in the exists subquery. However since I didn't mention this in my original question - I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is best optimize code if you want to get data from another table which primary key reference stored in another table
Invoice.objects.filter(note__invoice_id=OuterRef('pk'),)

Answer (score 0):

We should be able to clear the annotated field using the below method.

```
Invoice.objects.annotate(
    has_notes=Exists(Note.objects.filter(invoice_id=OuterRef('pk')))
).filter(has_notes=True).query.annotations.clear()
```